# JWPlayer cannot decode m4a audio in Firefox

Tags: firefox, audio, jwplayer

I'm having an issue with JWPlayer decoding audio in Firefox.  This is in an ASP.Net MVC application.

In Chrome and IE, this works without issue.  In Firefox, however, I am getting a js console error of `Media resource http://localhost:3126/RawData/PlayEchoicAudio/[id here].m4a could not be decoded.`

JWPlayer is being initialized with this code:

```
$(".playSound").live("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var url = $(this).attr("href");
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
    flashplayer: "/Static/js/JWPlayer/player.swf?1",
    file: url, 
    autostart: true,
    width: 1,
    height: 1,
    controls: false
  });
});
```

The code on the server side is:

```
    public virtual FileResult PlayEchoicAudio(Guid dataPointId) {
        var result = [query db here];

        return File(result.Audio, "audio/mp4", "sound.m4a");
    }
```

This code was originally returning a MIME Type of `audio/aac`.  According to [jw player documentation](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference) it should be `audio/mp4`.  This did not break the functionality in Chrome / IE, but it also did not make it work for Firefox.

Anybody have an idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have a link you can share?

Comment: Nothing public-facing.  I'll probably take MisterNeutron's advice and continue using JWPlayer for video, but switch to an <audio> tag for this case.

Comment: Okay. It might be something trivial, but without a link we would just be guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JW Player doesn't "decode" anything. It passes the audio file either to the browser's native HTML5 capabilities, or to Flash. It's just a steering script with some skinning for controls, ads, etc.

You appear to be using JW Player 5 (the "player.swf" is a dead giveaway), which is now terribly obsolete. Don't explicitly reference the Flash player (the old version you're using or the new version). The jwplayer.js script automatically calls the other scripts if it needs them (though they need to be colocated). Don't feed the player bogus dimensions - I believe that will break it under some circumstances.

See http://misterneutron.com/JW6audioNocontrols/

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction.  I'll mark this as the answer soon.

Comment: BTW, audio is a bit tricky. It's the unloved stepchild in JW Player. "Yeah, we have scripts for videos. And maybe audios, but we provide only limited support for them." I often think that you're better off just using the <audio> tag, which is supported in every browser other than IE8.